# Executing php on the background not happening when passing arguments

Tags: php, exec, command-line-interface

I am trying to execute a php on the background using this line of code:

```
echo exec("echo 'php -q file.php abcd' | at now 2>&1", $result);
```

it passes the arguments just fine as long as i don't require code igniter in file.php:

```
ob_start();
require_once('/path_to_code_igniter/index.php'); 
ob_end_clean();
```

when i do include code igniter, the script stops working. The only way i can make it work is erasing the arguments, so if i run:

```
echo exec("echo 'php -q file.php' | at now 2>&1", $result);
```

it works with code igniter require.  The error logs do not give any errors.
    It only shows 
`warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 148 at Wed Feb 26 16:02:00 2014`

Can anyone point me to a direction (I'm stuck in this for days)?

Comment: you dont want echo in there

Comment: Actually now it gives me Undefined variable: argv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing it all wrong. Codeigniter has a simple tutorial to call controllers through PHP CLI:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html

I guess the way I was loading Codeigniter externally was not correct, so when i passed parameters through CLI was messing up my script.